# Remember the last selection on Simple form

Tags: php, html

Is it possible that when

- I select something from the list
- And I click Go

Browser will remember my last choice from the list

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get" name="search_frm" id="serch_frm">
  <input name="serchStr" type="text" />
  <select name="list">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="client">table client</option> 
    <option value="user">table user</option> 
  </select>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

For example,

- if I chose from the list user table
- And hit Go

He will remain there

Comment: With `$_SESSION[''];` everything is possible

Comment: Use cookies ...............

Answer (score 1):

you can use sessions to access some data at a later time on a different script:

```
    session_start();

    $_SESSION = $POST['list'];
```

now the selected item from the list will remain there, as long as the browser is still opened.

if you want to remove the item from the session use:

```
   unset( $_SESSION['list'] );
```

and remember every time you use sessions you must use at the top of the file (always):

```
   session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a select "stick" you need to put the word `selected` inside the `<option>` tag before the value. In order to do that you’re going to need to dynamically generate the options using a `foreach` loop.  Inside the loop you’re going to look at the `$_REQUEST` and `if` it matches the value of what is being iterated in the loop you `echo selected`.

I’ve done this a dozen or more times and it works perfectly.

```
<?php
  $options = array("select", "client", "user");
?>
```

Then in the page:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get" name="search_frm" id="serch_frm">
  <input name="serchStr" type="text" />
  <select name="list">
  <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
    <option <?php if ($_GET['list'] == $option) { echo "selected"; } ?> value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $option;?></option>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

Comment: If it solved the problem can you please mark it as the solution.